# Grails dependency downloading

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

How can I make grails download artifacts(plugins and dependencies) to my local maven repository or the grails version folder so that i can save bandwidth when  create and run a new project or rather use them offline(as a version global cache maybe, instead of a project).

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: any, but i am currently using 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution) regarding dependancy resolution. There is a section about Local Resolvers which should allow you to use your local maven repository.

To specify your local Maven cache (~/.m2/repository) as a repository:

*BuildConfig.groovy*

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Obviously you do not needed to do that. `mavenLocal()` enabled by default. Here is the source code of that method `void mavenLocal() { // noop.. enabled by default }`